# how to disable Notification bar throughout the application?

Tags: android, notifications, handle, notification-bar

The user can launch other installed applications from my application and back to my activity when exiting launched application.I want to disable notification bar(showed status of wifi,gps,bluetooth etc...) or pulling down of notification bar throughout my application .
It works for my application when setting `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` But when launching other applications from my application ,possible to pull down Notification bar.

Is there any way to handle this?

Is it possible remove all notifications from Notification bar while my application is running?

How to make Notification bar not accessible from my application(a service is running throughout the application for checking currently running applications)?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [Same Question asked twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761555/how-to-disable-notification-bar-for-an-android-application)

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible, and thank the lord for that.

Would be pretty horrible if one rogue app would block my notification bar in all other parts of the system and other apps.

Comment: I want to make it and it is affected only for the applications which are launched from my applcation

Comment: As soon as you start up another app, that takes over. At max it will allow you to start a specific Activity or even pass some data (like with sharing files/texts) but that's it. From that point on, the other app takes over and it is out of your hands.

Comment: That means if I use a service throughout the application, does not affect the other application even it launch from my application?

Comment: A service is to execute a certain task at the background, to provide you with some data or to take action when something else happens in the system. It is not some supertool which influences the whole system. So no, you can not influence other apps from your app nor from any Service belonging to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could us a theme in your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

or use the following code snippet:

```
public class Activity
    extends android.app.Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: He's asking how to maintain the theme into other apps when his is minimized.